# Getting WebDriver from IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is it possible to get WebDriver from IWebElement?

I need the following extension:

```
public static bool HasFocus(this IWebElement e)
{
    var driver = ((????)e).WebDriver;

    var activeElement = driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
    return Equals(activeElement, e);
}
```

But don't know is it possible to cast the IWebElement to some type to get WebDriver.

Comment: The same issue occurs [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1490), I really believe this question deserves more attention, I don't think any of the answers so far provide a realistic solution. Not even sure this can be done...

Answer (score 8):

The best way to get the WebDriver from an IWebElement is to distinguish whether the Object type is WebElementProxy or not, like this:

```
if (this.webElement.GetType().ToString() == 
    "OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElementProxy")
{
 this.WebDriver = ((IWrapsDriver)this.webElement
                  .GetType().GetProperty("WrappedElement")
                  .GetValue(this.webElement, null)).WrappedDriver;
}
else
{
  this.WebDriver = ((IWrapsDriver)this.webElement).WrappedDriver;
}
```

Comment: Using your piece of code throws an `Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsDriver'`error.. I guess it is because I am using PageFactory to create my elements

Comment: I also use PageFactory, and this works in my case. Peehaps it'll be the version of selenium that you are using.

Comment: @SamuelRondeau-Millaire - I had the same issue with the version of Selenium I was using. Try my version below.

Answer (score 5):

I had recently the same problem but found out it's possible :)

This made my day: `var driver = ((IWrapsDriver)e).WrappedDriver;`

**Note:If you use PageFactory to get IWebElement it's NOT possible then.**

Comment: I'm getting InvalidCastException. Unable to cast object of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElementProxy' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsDriver'.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to get janmbaco's answer to work but as he points out this could be a version issue.

The following works for me with both `PageFactory` created `IWebElements` and regular create `IWebElements`. Using Selenium version `3.5.2` and chrome driver version `2.32.0`.

```cs
static IWebDriver GetWebDriverFromElement(IWebElement element)
{
  var realElement = element.GetType() != typeof(RemoteWebElement)
    ? element
    : ((IWrapsElement)element).WrappedElement;

  return ((IWrapsDriver)realElement).WrappedDriver;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@janmbaco answer works for me, just need to create a `static` method to make it easy.

```
public static IWebDriver GetWebDriverFromElement(this IWebElement element)
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;

    if (element.GetType().ToString() == "OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElementProxy")
    {
        driver = ((IWrapsDriver)element
                         .GetType().GetProperty("WrappedElement")
                         .GetValue(element, null)).WrappedDriver;
    }
    else
    {
        driver = ((IWrapsDriver)element).WrappedDriver;
    }
    return driver;
}
```

Usage:

```
IWebDriver driver = element.GetWebDriverFromElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with some of the suggestions failing with an InvalidCastException. This seemed to only be a problem in release builds and not debug builds.

I found this to work for me.

```
    public static IWebDriver GetWebDriver(this IWebElement element)
    {
        return ((IWrapsDriver)((IWrapsElement)element).WrappedElement).WrappedDriver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to get this reference missing is if you are using nuget package Selenium.WebDriver version bigger than v3.141.0. For some reason its missing from version 4alpha (for now)

Answer (score -4):

You can reference the driver that got the element like this.

```
    IWebDriver driver = element.WrappedDriver;
```

You can also just execute driver commands directly from the `element.WrappedDriver`

UPDATE:

`RemoteWebDriver` implements the `IWebDriver` interface.

`ChromeDriver`, `FirefoxDriver`, `IEDriver` all extend the  `RemoteWebDriver` class which includes the `IWebDriver` interface.

Similarly `RemoteWebElement` will do the same thing and has that property. So change your `IWebElement` to `RemoteWebElement` which implements the `IWebElement` interface and you will have that available to you.

In general try to keep it a class instance as the IWebElement interface instance has very few things that actually go with it.  If you keep it in the `RemoteWebDriver` and `RemoteWebElement` class instance you will get alot more options.

Comment: IWebElement doesn't have WrappedDriver property.

Comment: Updated answer with further clarification.

Comment: Downvoting this answer because, while technically correct, it encourages users to code to a specific implementation (`RemoteWebDriver`) rather than the interface (`IWebDriver` and `IWrapsDriver`). This directly contradicts the interface segregation principle and should be discouraged.

Comment: I can't cast my element to RemoteWebElement, as I'm using PageFactory to initialize page with IWebElements and it is of type OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElemetnProxy which is internal, and I can't access it to cast to it.

Comment: @JimEvans is there anything we could try to get WrappedDriver from WebElementProxy? I'm facing the same problem since switched to PageFactory.